# why wildfly server is asking me to add users even after adding user?

Tags: wildfly, wildfly-8, wildfly-10

mngmt-users.properties file. The users are added in the file but when I try to run the localhost it says it's running then if I try to view the admin console it is redirecting to http://localhost:9990/error/index_win.html. That tells the server is running but I could not open admin console.

```
#
# Properties declaration of users for the realm 'ManagementRealm' which is the default realm
# for new installations. Further authentication mechanism can be configured
# as part of the <management /> in standalone.xml.
#
# Users can be added to this properties file at any time, updates after the server has started
# will be automatically detected.
#
# By default the properties realm expects the entries to be in the format: -
# username=HEX( MD5( username ':' realm ':' password))
#
# A utility script is provided which can be executed from the bin folder to add the users: -
# - Linux
#  bin/add-user.sh
#
# - Windows
#  bin\add-user.bat
#
#$REALM_NAME=ManagementRealm$ This line is used by the add-user utility to identify the realm name already used in this file.
#
# On start-up the server will also automatically add a user $local - this user is specifically
# for local tools running against this AS installation.
#
# The following illustrates how an admin user could be defined, this
# is for illustration only and does not correspond to a usable password.
#
#admin=2a0923285184943425d1f53ddd58ec7a
tejaswini=25ab658c2861b2e64783aaa9ba95c2e5
aswini@19=388ced81791ddb1760b83dc4ec8b7a61
saisana=ff39d778414ab12d84fc4fa7fdacb634
alekya=d72e9c90345ce4d9290c3a2728b3cd60
prasad=c6c7c67cf343f6862d3b77bae9f61d17
teju=28b9e55b314fd60855a7843b4455dbed
```

Screen shot of added user

[image: Screen shot of added user]

Comment: Did you reload the server after you added a user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be u have tried to create specifically application user or management user when u ran the addUser utility,
please refer the below link for steps to register user

https://bgasparotto.com/add-user-wildfly